# Retrieving network profile avatar via API

Tags: support, api, network-profile, profile-picture

The network profile avatar (e.g. the one displayed on the [network profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/305991/jason-c)) seems to be its own thing, settable by copying it from a site of your choice.

Is there a way, given a user's network account ID, to retrieve that user's network profile avatar via the API, without having to manually determine and provide a `site` parameter (which would be an arbitrary choice anyways and may not match the user's network avatar)? Something that takes a network account ID and returns a profile image URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  There is currently no way to do that with the API (version 2.2)<sup>‡</sup>.

- None of the current API objects include any property for identifying the network profile page, user avatar.  For example, see [the network_user object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/network-user).
- The [network profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/305991/jason-c?tab=accounts) does not use a "secret" API to get the avatar either.  It's hard-coded into the page, EG:

  ```html
  <div class="user-avatar">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yiloe.png?s=128&amp;g=1" style="height: 128px;">
  </div>
  ```

  -- which makes sense as that page can function with javascript disabled.

So to get that avatar, you are currently forced to scrape the page.

Alternatively, you could get all the individual per-site avatars, via the API, and either present a list or choose the most-used one.

---

<sup>‡</sup> API version 2.3 appears to be in development, but is unlikely to add this feature due to low demand? (And no feature requests for it yet. ;)   )